# Found a bug in my hotel room, can anyone identify?

Tags: hotels, nature-and-wildlife, hygiene, identify-this, insects

I found 2 different kinds of bugs on 2 different nights in 2 different hotels. I don't think they are bed bugs, but can any one help identify them? They both were around 5 mm long.

[image: bug 1]
[image]

Edit:
It occurs to me that I might not be taken seriously without a little better visual context for these. To fix that I'll give some backup shots of the critters:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this is better suited on biology SE. They have a identify-species tag.

Comment: <insert programming joke here>

Comment: <insert Watergate hotel joke here>

Comment: Since he found it in a hotel. I would consider it relevant. Voted to reopen

Comment: You might want to add where this bug is found

Comment: So, how many bugs in total did you find?  Is there a biology thread on this?

Comment: In case anyone ever cares, neither of those is a [bed bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_bug). The second one is a [varied carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle); the first is rather unclear but it does look like a larva of the same species. According to Wikipedia, the hairs of the larva provoke an itchy rash in some people.